# Почему я не могу в качестве значения указателя **p присвоить название двумерного массива? Помогите разобраться

Tags: c++, указатели, двумерный-массив

[image: Структура двумерного массива]

Если я всё правильно понял, то при создании двумерного массива arr[2][3] создаётся переменная-указатель arr, которая указывает на безымянный массив из 2 указателей. Каждый из этих 2 указателей указывает на одномерный массив длиной в [3] элемента. Выходит указатель на указатель. Название массива указывает на первый элемент (в нашем случае этот элемент - указатель на одномерный массив). Однако при присваивании *pp = arr возникает ошибка..

Мы можем по другому указать на двумерный массив.

```
int arr[2][3]  { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
int (*p)[3] = arr; //указатель на массив из 3 элементов, т.е. arr[0]
```

Однако при просмотре следующих адресов и значений у меня появляется множество вопросов.

```
cout << p << " Значение p" << endl;
cout << *arr << " Значение arr" << endl;
cout << &arr << " Адрес arr" << endl;
cout << &arr[0] << " Адрес arr[0]" << endl;
cout << &arr[0][0] << " Адрес arr[0][0]" << endl;
cout << *arr[0] << " Значение arr[0]" << endl;
```

```
0000002FD98FF7A8 Значение p
0000002FD98FF7A8 Значение arr
0000002FD98FF7A8 Адрес arr
0000002FD98FF7A8 Адрес arr[0]
0000002FD98FF7A8 Адрес arr[0][0]
1 Значение arr[0]
```

Я могу ещё понять совпадение значения arr и адреса arr[0], но остальные совпадения и единица для меня загадка.. Будто бы и не создавался никакой безымянный массив с указателями, а название просто указывает на самый первый элемент..
Где-то я видимо что-то не так понял, либо чего-то не знаю. Помогите понять

Comment: При создании массива никаких указателей не создается, картинка не правильная. `int arr[2][3]` состоит из 6 идущих подряд `int`. Имя переменной-массива не является указателем. Однако может неявно приводиться к нему, как например в `*arr`.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь визуализатором https://pythontutor.com там все переменные, указатели будет видно и стрелки укажут куда и на что указывают, ну и значения соответственно. Но он не любит русский ;)

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение и за сайт!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, вы получаете указатель не на массив указателей, а на блок памяти из 2*3 = 6 `int`'ов. Просто компилятор точно знает размер массива, так что ему не сложно обратиться к элементу, скажем, `arr[1][1]` как к 1*3+1 = 4-му элементу в этом блоке `int`ов.

Comment: А точно ли это указатель на блок памяти из 6 int'ов, а не на блок памяти (массив) из 3 int'ов. Ведь если мы посмотрим значение *(arr + 1), то мы не прибавим ещё один двумерный массив, а именно прибавим одномерный массив. Будем указывать на следующую строчку

Comment: Ну а сто такое блок из двух `int[3]`, как не блок из 6 `int`? И да, указатель сместится на 3 `int` и станет указывать на третий (если считать от нуля) элемент в общем блоке.

Comment: Хорошо. Могу ли я все выше сказанное резюмировать следующим образом, что имя массива указывает на блок памяти из 6 int'ов, а если быть конкретней, то на подблок из 3 int'ов, т.е. на одномерный массив => на первый элемент, поэтому все адреса и совпадают. Ну и ещё мы понимаем, что имя массива указывает именно на подмассив, т.е. имеет тип int(звездочка)[3]. Типы указателей при присвоении между собой должны совпадать, поэтому мы не можем сделать (две звезды)p = arr ( int(две звезды) != int(звездочка)[] ) и также не можем *p = arr     p.s. "звездочка" и т.п. из-за форматирования

Comment: Ну, массивы вообще напрямую не присваиваются, но в принципе, насколько я могу судить (я больше практик, а не теоретик в стандартах), то все верно. Звездочку можно записывать с обратной косой чертой — \\*, или как код, в обратных одинарных кавычках.

Comment: Спасибо за совет и ответы. Вроде как стало понятней